# Is there a way to export the styling in vite library mode for a react app?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass, vite

I have a vite react TS app with JSX components, mudule.scss and global css files.
When I build it using Library Mode I get separated .js, .d.ts and .css.
But when I install it in any other app, the styling do not get applied.

The package works as expected, but the styling does not work at all.

Comment: Publish the css files with the rest of your library then link to them either via `import`, `@import`, `importmap`, etc. depending on the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using: [vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js)

```html
//...
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from 'vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js'
//...

export default defineConfig({
  //...
  plugins: [
    react(),
    //...
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin(), // HERE
  ],
  //...
})
```